# Persistent query usage in Snowflake from Python flask app

Tags: sql, flask, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a public facing web server (Flask) using a Snowflake backend as the DB. I used https://github.com/app-generator/flask-volt-dashboard as a template though heavily modified it. (I can post the public link if that doesn't count as promotion.) However, every few minutes, I'm seeing the following queries being executed by the app even though it's not in use. I combed through the code but I'm not sure what's causing it. I believe it's something to do with the SQLAlchemy library, but I'm not sure.

App is currently hosted in AWS using Elastic Beanstalk.

[Queries Being Executed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbBOM.png)

I've tried code review and disabling all authentication modules, but no luck so far.

Comment: I would guess that some process is running to keep the connection to Snowflake alive. The SQL looks meaningless so I think it’s the fact a query is running, rather than what the query is, that is important

Comment: without digging through the github code, could you confirm that this is using the standard Snowflake python connector and/or Snowflake SQLAlchemy connector?  Latest version?  This looks like something I'd expect from a generic connector that tries to keep a session open.  And what is the authentication method being used to Snowflake?

Comment: and your screenshot doesn't show whether those queries are successful or using a warehouse.  If they aren't using a warehouse, then no harm, right?

Comment: @MikeWalton they are using a warehouse so are costing me quite a few credits apparently.

With regards to the connector, I'm using the standard Snowflake SQLAlchemy connector using username/PW auth.

Comment: It looks like a keep-alive action to me.  I don't know the settings offhand to turn that off, though.  You may also want to double-check on the latest version.